# Trying to fill array with user input (string) by using input.nextLine(), but prints output twice and doesn't ask for input the first time

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, input, output

This is a snippet of code from a program I am writing:

```
// User is asked how many options he wants to fill in.
System.out.print("How many options do you have: ");
int numberOfOptions = input.nextInt();

// Array declared for storing user input 
String[] options = new String [numberOfOptions];

// The array options is filled with user input in a for loop.
for(int i = 0; i < numberOfOptions; i++){
    System.out.print("What is option " + (i + 1) + ": ");                
        options[i] = input.nextLine();  
    }
```

[This is the output I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlM8z.jpg)
when it's executed. As you can see in the screenshot, it prints "What is option..." twice. It doesn't ask for input the first time it prints what is option 1.

I have tried using input.next(). This doesn't give me any problems, it works just fine. It just isn't wat I want because I want the user to be able to input whole sentences instead of only words.

How can I solve this problem, did I do anything wrong?

Comment: This question must have answered before. In very short, input.nextInt() does not consume carriage return. So at very first input.nextLine() get the carriage.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-nextint-or-other-nextfoo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your probleme is because the first call to nextLine() method is immediately after an nextInt() method which didn't read the newline character, and the first nextLine() read that newline character.
The solution is to call a nextLine() after nextInt()

```
int numberOfOptions = input.nextInt();
input.nextLine();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer :)